# Change UI font size in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, resize

How can I change the size of the User Interface font in Android Studio? All the previous answers focus on changing the font size in the editor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- File => Settings => Appearance & Behavior => Appearance
- Override default fonts by (not recommended)
- Choose size => Ok
  [image]